# In a Linux environment, which permission is related to downloading a log?

Tags: linux, logging

In Linux, I have logs folder for storing logs. I have an application to view and download logs in that folder.  When there is no 'r' permission, I can't read a log. (of course).  ( r - read, w- write, x-execute )

***I am wondering, downloading logs is related to which permission?  x? or w?***

As far as I know, w is related to editing, modifying, and deleting files.
X is to run and execute a file. so downloading has to do with permission 'x'? Or maybe as long as I have 'r' permission to view a file, downloading has nothing to do with 'x' or 'w'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading is the same as viewing which is the same as reading. To download you need to read!

Which, on Linux, it translates to read on the file and execute on all the parent directories.

Quick link to the relevant [Wiki page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/File_system_permissions#Permissions)

Comment: Can I get a reason why the downvote? As far as I know my answer is correct and pertinent to the question